# How to lower volume on microphone input before outputting through headphones? (Using a DSP)

Tags: audio, adc, raspberry-pi, dsp, decibel

As part of a senior engineering course, my partner and I decided on tackling the problem of hearing loss in youth, and went with a more preventative approach, trying to reduce the amount of cases rather than cure hearing loss. In our efforts, we decided that it would be most appealing and effective to design a pair of headphones that are of decent quality while having an "Active listening" feature as well, but instead of using that feature to make low sounds louder, we wanted to do just the opposite to prevent volume from reaching a certain decibel level to prevent hearing loss from occuring. I have a post regarding this same type of question here (http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=386968.msg2676322#msg2676322) where I found out that an arduino would not be best suited for this type of project, but instead to use Digital Signal Processor.

This is where I am so far, not sure on how to proceed using said DSP to convert the analog signal to digital and then lower voltage before converting it back to analog signal. We would probably be using a raspberry pi as a hub for power and usb inputs.

Edit: We plan to use TI Code Compiler Studios as well as a programmable usb DSP if possible.

The main questions I need answered right now are these

- Can this be accomplished in a reasonable time period? (<2 Months time?)
- Would I need to create my own audio input and output devices, or could I use an existing pair of headphones to receive and play sound that is converted?
- Where can I look for additional help regarding this type of problem?

Thanks to all who took the time to read through this, I know it was long, and thanks to anyone in advance for any reply I receive.

Comment: You could do this entirely in the analog domain, either with some sort of automatic gain control or dynamic range compression: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression

Comment: You already mentioned Raspberry pi. So one approach would be to take a platform that runs an unix-variant, get one with a sound chip or attached a sound card. Use the existing driver support. You didn't mentioned any latency requirement, so it shouldn't take much of a processor to do what you want.

Comment: Are you aware of noise-cancelling headphones such as those made by [Bose](https://www.bose.co.uk/GB/en/home-and-personal-audio/headphones/noise-cancelling-headphones/)?

Answer (score 1):

Using a DSP or a Raspberry Pi to limit the sound level from a pair of headphones seems to be overkill. All that you are trying to do is to impose an upper limit on the sound level, which is exactly what a simple analog AGC (automatic gain control) circuit does. Have a look at this Maxim Microphone amplifier with AGC [MAX9814](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9814.pdf%20here). This single chip does almost everything you need, although it will not drive headphones directly, you will need a small headphone amplifier such as a MAX9820. It should be possible to build this circuit onto a PCB of about 3 x 2 cm, it can be battery powered, and a small coin cell should last several months.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention, as this is so much simpler than our original idea. However, I dont believe I have enough experience to create the board onto PCB right away. Would a project like this be able to be completed on a breadboard given external power? Also could I use my existing headphones (has both audio and mic cables, or usb if you want to use the sound card) to test a solution like this?